# Excel VBA Object Required

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, vlookup

i try to update a cell using vlookup bu it has object required error 
can u solve what's my wrong?

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.txt_ruhsat_no.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HAKEDİŞ").Range("A:BZ"), 51, 0) = Me.txt_metrekare.Value
```

Comment: Assigning a value to the result of a VLookup makes no sense.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: When assigning e.g. 1 to a variable x, you would use x=1 and not 1=x. Applying the same principle to your case, you should use 'Me.txt_metrekare.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Me.txt_ruhsat_no.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HAKEDİŞ").Range("A:BZ"), 51, 0)'. Some one might wonder how this did happen: The equation might have been in an If statement (where it wouldn't matter which expression is on which side of the equal sign) and just automatically got copy/pasted without thinking what it does. No biggy.

Comment: thx for your helps i found different way
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HAKEDİŞ")

Dim lr As Long
lr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Me.txt_ruhsat_no.Value, ThisWorkbook.Sheets("HAKEDİŞ").Range("A:A"))
sh.Range("AY" & lr).Value = Me.txt_metrekare.Value